# Dynamic Aggregation in Polars

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I'd like to check the percentage of nulls for a set of columns in my dataframe, grouped by a different set of columns.

The columns in the dataframe may change, so I'd like to be able to pass in a list of columns to group by and a list of columns to count nulls for.

Grouping easily takes a list of column names, but I can't find a way to do this for the counts. I can only do it by writing a line for each column I want to count nulls for:

```
df = df.groupby(by=list_of_grouping_fields)\
    .agg([
        pl.count().alias('Row_Count'),
        pl.col("INVOICE NUMBER").null_count().alias('INVOICENUMBER_nullcount'),
        pl.col("ORDER NUMBER").null_count().alias('ORDERNUMBER_nullcount')
        ])
```

This seems inefficient and would require me to come back and edit the code if the columns changed.

Ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
df = df.groupby(by=list_of_grouping_fields)\
    .agg([
        pl.count().alias('Row_Count'),
        pl.col([list_of_agg_fields]).null_count().alias([list_of_aliases])
        ])
```

Is there a way to do this with Polars?

Comment: What you have should already work, you would just replace `.alias([list_of_aliases])` with `.suffix('_nullcount')`

Answer (score 1):

[`agg`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.dataframe.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html#polars.dataframe.groupby.GroupBy.agg) takes variadic positional args and keyword args, so you should be able to do

```py
.agg(
  pl.count().alias('Row_Count'),
  *[pl.col(af).null_count().alias(al) for af,al in zip(list_of_agg_fields, list_of_aliases)]
)
```

or, since keyword args is a shortcut for alias:

```py
.agg(
  pl.count().alias('Row_Count'), # or Row_Count=pl.count()
  **{al : af.null_count() for af,al in zip(list_of_agg_fields, list_of_aliases}
)
```

There was a big effort a few months back to make a lot of core function signatures be more flexible like this. Note that `groupby` takes variadic positional as well, the first argument being either a single expression or iterable of expressions is a bit of a leftover from before this effort.